# Implement helmet-csp on individual routes

Tags: node.js, express, content-security-policy, helmet.js

I'm creating a sample Express app to demonstrate Content-Security-Policy (CSP) headers and am trying to use [helmet-csp](https://github.com/helmetjs/csp).

All of the documentation for helmet-csp shows it used as standard third-party-middleware via `app.use(csp({ ... }))` - this adds the CSP headers to *every* route in my application, but I want to customize it on individual routes.

**Sample App**

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var csp = require('helmet-csp');
var app = express();

app.use(csp({
    directives: {
        frameSrc: ["'none'"]
    }
}));

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.send('hi, :wave: =]');
});

app.get('/frameable', (request, response) => {
    response.send('you can frame me!');
});

http.createServer(app).listen(80, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('error', err);
    }
});
```

With the above, *every* route receives the CSP header:

> Content-Security-Policy: frame-src 'none'

In the `/frameable` route, I would want to override this CSP header to be:

> Content-Security-Policy: frame-src 'self'

Whenever I need/want to customize a header set by helmet-csp on a per-route basis, do I need to manually override them inside each `app.get` with a line such as:

```
response.setHeader('Content-Security-Policy', "frame-src 'self'");
```

Or is there a way to do this via helmet-csp itself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A custom middleware is able to change headers, just add it after the `use(csp)`

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.url == '/frameable') {
        res.set('Content-Security-Policy', 'frame-src \'self\'');
    }
    next();
});
```

You can also chain middleware, since it is a function that returns a function:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var middleware;

    if (req.url == '/frameable') {
        middleware = csp({
            directives: {
                frameSrc: ["'self'"]
            }
        });
    } else {
        middleware = csp({
            directives: {
                frameSrc: ["'none'"]
            }
        });
    }

    middleware(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: That's directly modifying the headers - that much is easy to do (see the end of my question); I'm curious if it's possible to do this via the middleware itself on a per-route basis. Case-in-point, manually setting a small CSP header isn't the end of the world, but when there are multiple headers with multiple options and they're custom on multiple routes - it would be much friendlier to use `helmet-csp` instead of manually defining them each time.

Comment: Chaining middleware allows some re-use

Comment: Oh this is great - thank you! Knowing that this is a middleware type thing (and not tied to the library) is awesome, it'll help out a lot in the future. Thanks (^_^)

Comment: @jasonpenny Thanks for the solution! I'm getting TypeError: middleware is not a function if I try the second suggestion. What am I missing? I use helmet.

Answer (score 10):

This behavior is built into Express.

Express lets you specify multiple request handlers per route. Because `csp` returns a route handler, you can add it before *your* route handler:

```
app.get('/frameable', csp({
    directives: {
        frameSrc: ["'self'"]
    }
}), (request, response) => {
    response.send('you can frame me!');
});
```

If you prefer to split things out a bit, you could do something like this:

```
var normalCspHandler = csp({
    directives: {
        frameSrc: ["'none'"]
    }
});

var frameSelfCspHandler = csp({
    directives: {
        frameSrc: ["'self'"]
    }
});

app.use(normalCspHandler);

app.get('/frameable', frameSelfCspHandler, (request, response) => {
    response.send('you can frame me!');
});
```

(By the way, I maintain Helmet, so let me know if you have any feedback!)

Comment: Ah, this is really good to know - thank you very much for your answer =]